# Firefox cannot drawImage from an offscreen canvas controlled by a worker

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker, offscreen-canvas

I tried to transfer an image drawn to an offscreen canvas by a web worker to a visible canvas. It works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. No error was thrown in the console, but the visible canvas remains blank. Below is my complete program (`index.html`). Is this an issue with how Firefox handles worker and canvas? Is there a fix to this? Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      const w = 600, h = 400;
      const blob = new Blob(['(' + render.toString() + ')()'], {type: 'text/javascript'});
      const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      const offs = document.getElementById('worker').transferControlToOffscreen();
      worker.postMessage({ msg: 'load', canvas: offs }, [offs]);

      // draw image in offscreen canvas
      document.getElementById('render').addEventListener('click', function () {
        worker.postMessage({ msg: 'draw' });
      });

      // transfer image to main canvas
      document.getElementById('transfer').addEventListener('click', function () {
        const img = document.getElementById('worker');
        const ctx = document.getElementById('main').getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
      });
    });

    // worker for rendering
    function render() {
      let canvas;
      onmessage = function(e) {
        if (e.data.msg === 'load') {
          canvas = e.data.canvas;
        } else if (e.data.msg === 'draw') {
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
          ctx.fillRect(150, 150, 300, 200);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>
      <canvas id="main" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
      <canvas id="worker" width="600" height="400" style="display: none"></canvas>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="render">Render</button>
      <button id="transfer">Transfer</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, and I filed [BUG 1833496](https://bugzil.la/1833496).
For a fix, we'll need to wait a bit, but the last few bugs I opened against their `OffscreenCanvas` young implementation were fixed rapidly, so there is hope this one gets fixed too.

If you need a workaround, you could [transfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/transferToImageBitmap) your `OffscreenCanvas` to an `ImageBitmap`, transfer that back to your main thread through `postMessage()` and draw it when needed:

```js
const w = 600, h = 400;
const blob = new Blob(['(' + render.toString() + ')()'], {type: 'text/javascript'});
const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
const offs = document.getElementById('worker').transferControlToOffscreen();
worker.postMessage({ msg: 'load', canvas: offs }, [offs]);

// We'll store the canvas bitmap when ready
let source;
worker.onmessage = ({data}) => {
  if (data.msg === "bitmap") {
    source = data.bmp;
  }
};

// draw image in offscreen canvas
document.getElementById('render').addEventListener('click', function () {
  worker.postMessage({ msg: 'draw' });
});

// transfer image to main canvas
document.getElementById('transfer').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (!source) {
    console.log("no source available yet");
    return;
  }
  const ctx = document.getElementById('main').getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
});

// worker for rendering
function render() {
  let canvas;
  onmessage = function(e) {
    if (e.data.msg === 'load') {
      canvas = e.data.canvas;
      // I removed a "draw" step here, up to you to reimplement as you need
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
      ctx.fillRect(150, 150, 300, 200);
      // let main thread draw us (https://bugzil.la/1833496)
      const bmp = canvas.transferToImageBitmap();
      postMessage({msg: "bitmap", bmp}, [bmp]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <button id="render">Render</button>
    <button id="transfer">Transfer</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <canvas id="main" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <canvas id="worker" width="600" height="400" style="display: none"></canvas>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for noting the same issue and reporting it in Bugzilla